# How to create a wrapper component on top of existing component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

So basically I am using quasar for one of my projects. I have this [dialog component](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#dialog-api) that I am using at many places and in those places some stuff have become redundant so I want to create a dialog wrapper component called `my-dialog`.

**my-dialog.vue**

```js
<template>
  <q-dialog v-bind="props">
    <template v-for="(_, slotName) in slots" #[slotName]="slotData">
      <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="slotData" />
    </template>
  </q-dialog>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { QDialog, QDialogProps } from "quasar";

type Slots = QDialog["$slots"];

const slots = defineSlots<Slots>();
const props = defineProps<QDialogProps>();
</script>
```

Below is an example of a place I am trying to use it

confirm-dialog.vue

```js
<template>
  <my-dialog ref="dialogRef" @hide="onDialogHide">
    <q-card>
      <q-card-section>
        {{ title }}
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-section>{{ message }}</q-card-section>

      <q-card-actions align="right">
        <q-btn :label="cancel" flat color="primary" @click="onDialogCancel" />
        <q-btn :label="ok" flat color="primary" @click="onDialogOK" />
      </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
  </my-dialog>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { useDialogPluginComponent } from "quasar";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import MyDialog from "./my-dialog.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "ConfirmDialog",

  props: {
    cancel: {
      type: String,
      default: "cancel",
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    ok: {
      type: String,
      default: "confirm",
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "title",
    },
  },
  emits: useDialogPluginComponent.emitsObject,
  setup() {
    return {
      ...useDialogPluginComponent(),
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

I get the below error when trying to do this.

```
quasar.esm.js:40199 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dialogRef.value.show is not a function
```

I could customize it more later but for some reason the very basic functionality does not seem to be working correctly. Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

So, the `dialogRef` has no method exposed named `show` (dialogRef.value.show is not a function).

This happens because the ref is likely pointing to the wrapper component (my-dialog) rather than the actual q-dialog component.

you need to expose the `show` and other methods from the inner `q-dialog` component to your wrapper `my-dialog` component and then use them in the parent `confirm-dialog`.

Alright. So let's jump on the code:

`my-dialog.vue`:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// ... other imports ...

const dialogRef = ref(null);

// Exposing the show method
const show = () => {
  dialogRef.value.show();
};

// Also hide
const hide = () => {
  dialogRef.value.hide();
};

// expose these methods
defineExpose({ show, hide });  
</script>

<template>
  <!-- using ref here to connect it -->
  <q-dialog v-bind="props" ref="dialogRef">
    <!-- rest of your template -->
  </q-dialog>
</template>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this does provide some insight I thought `v-bind="props"` was doing that for me. also it gives me other errors further like

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'unmount')"
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'key')"

I assume there are other properties in q-dialog component that are not being exposed. Is there a way to expose them all together instead of one by one?

Comment: @Nik You can expose the whole qdialog's dialogRef then instead of separate functions

Comment: @estus-flask could you guide me on how to do that?


"const dialogRef = ref<QDialog>();
defineExpose({ dialogRef });"

I tried simply adding the preceding code in my-dialog.vue script but it did not work.

Comment: @Nik What didn't work exactly? You should access it as dialogRef.value.dialogRef.value then, the naming is misleading

Comment: @estus-flask I am still getting the "TypeError: dialogRef.value.show is not a function" error when I try to expose the dialogRef using the following code

"const dialogRef = ref<QDialog>(); defineExpose({ dialogRef });"

Comment: @Nik But it should be dialogRef.value.dialogRef.value.show in the latter case. Generally it's done like the answer suggests as show & hide are enough for public api, and your problem with "Cannot read properties of null" is very specific to your case and needs to be debugged